# Traceability matrix in HPQC 10

Tags: matrix, report, hp-quality-center, traceability

We need to create a report with traceability matrix between requirements and testcases.
I know HPQC 11 has a specific function for it, but I have only HPQC 10.

Is there any way to create such a matrix in HPQC10?

PS: example of matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceability_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it programmatically with the OTA API. For example you can start with a requirement and list all of the child requirements with the tests which cover them. Here is the example code in Ruby:

```
reqs = req_factory.GetChildrenList(94) # get the start-requirement by id
reqs.each do |req|
  tests = req.GetCoverList
  puts "#{req.Name} is covered by #{tests.Count} tests:"
  tests.each { |test| puts "#{test.Name}" }
end
```

Output:

```
Req A is covered by 3 tests:
Test A
Test B
Test C
Req B is covered by 2 tests:
Test X
Test Y
```

To get the requirements covered by a test case, use the function `GetCoverList()` of the Test Object.

This should give you all the data needed to create a traceability matrix.

Comment: thanks, I thinking about using API, but it not so comfortably. Are sure that no any other way to create such Matrix?

Comment: There might be other ways—even simpler ones. But the one sketched above is the only way I know. But I don't really know QC very well, I know only the OTA API. Maybe you can create some kind of Excel Report which gives you the same information.

Comment: I'll back up Roland.  There's no "built-in" way to create the matrix in QC10.  I suggest you get comfortable with the OTA API because it is very useful for solving problems where QC does not provide a solution.  Excel report might work, but would still be using OTA API concepts.